# Trimming a PHP string from system() output

Tags: php, trim

I'm trying to trim a string that I get from doing system("dsquery user");
The output is like this from running the command:

```
    "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
    "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
    "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
```

What I'm trying to do is that I need to get every user, so I need to get the part after CN= and store that in an array.. 
This is the code right now:

```
<?php
$s=system("dsquery user");
$t=explode(" ", str_replace('"', "", $s));
for($i=0;isset($t[$i]);$i++)
{
    $y=explode("=", $t[$i]);
    $a[]=substr($y[1], 0, strpos($y[1], ","));
}
for($j=0;isset($a[$j]);$j++)
{
    echo $a[$j]."<br>";
}
?>
```

But the only thing I get is the last user, so in this case krbtgt..
Any help is appreciated a lot!

Is there any hidden characters that's missed?

```
Copy pasted from terminal:

    "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[End of Line(LF)]
    "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[End of Line(LF)]
    "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[End of Line(LF)]
Copy pasted from system output:
    "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[Space]"CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[Space]"CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[Space]krbtgt
```

Comment: You need to define `$a` outside the first for loop with `$a = array();`

Comment: Hmm, didn't work what exactly do you mean? 
Like this?
<?php
$s=system("dsquery user");
$t=explode(" ", str_replace('"', "", $s));
$a = array();
for($i=0;isset($t[$i]);$i++)
{
    $y=explode("=", $t[$i]);
    $a[]=substr($y[1], 0, strpos($y[1], ","));
}
for($j=0;isset($a[$j]);$j++)
{
    echo $a[$j]."<br>";
}
?>

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved easily using [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$out = <<<END
    "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
    "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
    "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local"
END;

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/CN=([^,"]+)/', $out, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

It prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Administrator
    [1] => Users
    [2] => Guest
    [3] => Users
    [4] => krbtgt
    [5] => Users
)
```

Comment: See it in action: http://3v4l.org/H5f2l (based on what input data you provided in the question).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $a before using it:

```
$s="CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=server,DC=local";
$t=explode(" ", str_replace('"', "", $s));
$a = array();
for($i=0;isset($t[$i]);$i++){
    $y=explode("=", $t[$i]);
    $a[]=substr($y[1], 0, strpos($y[1], ","));
}
for($j=0;isset($a[$j]);$j++)    {
    echo $a[$j] . "\n";
}
```

revising the answer based on @axiac's answer:

```
$s= <<<SYSTEM
    "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[End of Line(LF)]
    "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[End of Line(LF)]
    "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local"[End of Line(LF)]
SYSTEM;

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/CN=([^,"]+)/', $s, $matches);

echo print_r($matches, true);
```

This works great and prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => CN=Administrator
            [1] => CN=Users
            [2] => CN=Guest
            [3] => CN=Users
            [4] => CN=krbtgt
            [5] => CN=Users
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Administrator
            [1] => Users
            [2] => Guest
            [3] => Users
            [4] => krbtgt
            [5] => Users
        )

)
```

then you can loop over the $matches array like you were already doing...

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought it should too, but the only thing it outputs is the following:
"CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local" "CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local" "CN=krbtgt,CN=Users,DC=dennizserver,DC=local" krbtgt
I've tried all kinds of crazy stuff but I have no idea how the system() output is different than just using the string..

Comment: oic, can you open the system output in a text editor with invisible characters showing and add that to your question, please? I bet you have newline characters or something that are messing up the searching through the strings...

Comment: Added it to my question!

Comment: So, yeah, it had invisible characters in it, you will need to adjust your find in strings for that...

Comment: *"revising"*? This is a new name for copy-paste?

Comment: not at all, I added your regex to be helpful and combined ti with his string from teh actual output to be as helpful as possible. I gave you credit even, I am not sure what your problem is, revising an answer once the OP submits more info is a very common practice on SO. I could have left my answer not using regex but I thought I was ackowledging that you actually had a better way to do the string parsing and included that in the answer, I would take it as a complement. The point of SO is to give the OP and later users the best possible answer...

Comment: and if you just downvoted me vindictively, that is REALLY not in the spirit of SO...

Comment: @axiac I'm seeing DrCord's answer posted 45 minutes and your answer 33 minutes ago. Maybe you were still editing your post longer than the DrCord but that's no reason to down vote a correct answer.

Comment: @Protomancer does the mention of my name and answer as the source of their current "revision" (edited 20 minutes ago) counts?

Comment: @axiac He did credit you.  If I need to play arbiter here I would wager DrCord is trying to craft a good answer. Isn't stack overflow for contributing to great answers and helping people? Besides with your 6k+ rep, spread the wealth a little.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by using regex.
The problem was that the system output only gave me the last line so I needed to change the system to a exec and use the output variable as an array and make a loop through it. 
This is the final solution:

```
<?php
$s=exec("dsquery user", $retval);
echo "<br \>";
$matches = array();
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
    preg_match_all('/CN=([^,"]+)/', $retval[$i], $matches);
    echo $matches[1][0];
}
?>
```